# Voltage source on both sides of a transformer

Tags: voltage, transformer, concept

What will happen if we apply voltage sources (AC) on both the primary and secondary side of a transformer?

How will the coil and the flux produced inside it behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you model it as linear component, and your voltage sources as ideal:

It's a linear component. Use the superposition principle to figure out what happens if you set either of these voltage sources to 0V and then add the results.

If you don't model the transformer as linear component: You'll have to consider the nonlinear effects; it's likely these are complex enough that nothing short of a finite-timestep simulation will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks got it. So we can refer secondary voltage source on primary side, find the equivalent voltage source and consider the modified transformer as standard transformer. Am I right?

Comment: Not quite sure, to be honest. But I don't know how you "modified" your transformer, or what a "standard transformer" is.

Answer (score 0):

What if your primary winding was [Litz wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) or a [bifilar winding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil). Each individual winding can be regarded as a secondary winding except you are parallel connecting them all to one voltage source. It's exactly the same scenario as raised in your question.

### Bifilar wound toroid

[image]

### Litz wire

[image]

Litz wire picture from [here](https://www.e-magnetica.pl/doku.php/litz_wire).